# Почему не работает CSS3 анимация в firefox и opera!?

Tags: css-animation, анимация

В гугл хром отображается корректно, в опере не хочет работать.

```
.pane_input{
animation-name:fPulse;
-webkit-animation-name:fPulse;
-moz-animation-name:fPulse;
-webkit-animation-duration:2s;
-moz-animation-duration:2s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
-moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out}

@keyframes fPulse
  {
  0% {
    border-color: #ffffff;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: #FF0000;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: #ffffff;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fPulse
  {
  0% {
    border-color: #ffffff;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: #FF0000;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: #ffffff;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fPulse
  {
  0% {
    border-color: #ffffff;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: #FF0000;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: #ffffff;
  }
}

@keyframes titlePulse
  {
  0% {
    color: #000000;
  }
  50% {
    color: #FF0000;
  }
  100% {
    color: #000000;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes titlePulse
  {
  0% {
    color: #000000;
  }
  50% {
    color: #FF0000;
  }
  100% {
    color: #000000;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes titlePulse
  {
  0% {
    color: #000000;
  }
  50% {
    color: #FF0000;
  }
  100% {
    color: #000000;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Всё нормально работает](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/yvz8j/1/), даже в осле 10 проверил. Добавьте вендорные префиксы там, где не хватает.

Answer (score 0):

```
@keyframes titlePulse { 0% { color: #000000; } 50% { color: #FF0000; } 100% { color: #000000; } }

@-moz-keyframes titlePulse { 0% { color: #000000; } 50% { color: #FF0000; } 100% { color: #000000; } }

@-webkit-keyframes titlePulse { 0% { color: #000000; } 50% { color: #FF0000; } 100% { color: #000000; } }

@-ms-keyframes titlePulse { 0% { color: #000000; } 50% { color: #FF0000; } 100% { color: #000000; } }

@-o-keyframes titlePulse { 0% { color: #000000; } 50% { color: #FF0000; } 100% { color: #000000; } }
```

Comment: Так тоже не работает

Comment: Потому что это файерфокс и опера. Такой вот ответ.

Comment: Просто эти браузеры пока не реализовали данные тестовые CSS3 возможности (и не факт что реализуют в будущем). Используйте JavaScript анимацию (например с помощью JQuery

Comment: @Arc и @MDJHD , вы бы хоть попробовали что ли...

Answer (score 0):

Пример скрипта анимации на jQuery ( из книги Самков Г.А. jQuery. Сборник рецептов)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#right").click(function(){
        $(".block").animate({"left": "+=50px"}, "slow");
    });
    $("#left").click(function(){
        $(".block").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");
    });
    });
</script>
```